# Don't show #N/A in formula run on empty cells

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a select box that is used to populate an adjacent row via `VLOOKUP`. I am applying the formula to the entire column, but because I don't have selected any value in origin, the formula show `#N/A`.

How to prevent Excel from showing this?

[image: excel]

Comment: Either use IFERROR to suppress errors, or test for an empty lookup cell first: `=IF(B2="","",VLOOKUP(...))`

Comment: Or use XLOOKUP and provide the value it should show when no match is found.

Comment: With if condition, i have problema resolved.